# Callback function variable order in "Interactive Data Visualization for the Web"

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, data-visualization

In chapter 5 of Scott Murray's "Interactive Data Visualization for the Web", he writes: "Note that error must be the first parameter, and data the second", when referring to callback function.

Why is this the case?

Comment: Here's the relevant bit of code [where d3 calls the callback](https://github.com/d3/d3-request/blob/master/src/request.js#L115).  What's amusing is even if you just defined it as `function(data)`, `d3` has handled that case with `fixCallback`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know what callback function Murray is talking about. But it's a convention which is used in many asynchronous functions.

Let's turn the question around. Suppose you're calling a function `fn` provided by someone else. It could be from another part of your code, a constructor from an npm module, whatever. If you tried calling `fn(b, a)` instead of `fn(a, b)`, it would go horribly wrong. For example, if `fn = function(x, y) { return x - y; }`, then `fn(2, 5)` would return `-3` and `fn(5, 2)` would return `3`.

Your question is exactly the same situation in reverse: You are defining a function and someone else is calling it. The provider of the asynchronous function has promised to call your callback with the error and data as arguments, *in that order*. So if you treat your first argument as the error and your second as the data, it will work.

There's nothing stopping people from creating asynchronous functions which call their callbacks with the data as the first argument and the error as the second. But I don't know of anyone else who does this, so if anyone did it would just be confusing and pointless.

Comment: Thanks! `d3.csv("myfile.csv", function(error, data){
   if(error){
    console.log(error);
   }

   else{
    dataset = data;
   }
  });` So in this case, d3.csv is calling the function? And d3.csv expects to receive (error, data) in that order?

Comment: (A gentle suggestion: if you removed "I'm not buying the book just to answer this question", your answer would seem a lot friendlier!)

Comment: I didn't mean to be unfriendly, but I've removed that part anyway. "So in this case, d3.csv is calling the function?" Yes, d3 will cause your callback function to be called (either directly or through some other module which d3 depends on). "And d3.csv expects to receive (error, data) in that order?" No, your function will receive them in that order from d3.csv. (We don't know or care how exactly d3 receives these arguments.)

Comment: Ah, right, that makes sense. And thank you very much for your help (and for making stackoverflow friendlier)! :)